# PostgreSQL procedure that will return random records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write a procedure in PostgreSQL to give me some random records for selected table. How can I do this? I can't find any good tutorials in web...

I know that I can get random records in many way from PostgreSQL. But I have very big tables and most of them causes performance issue. I also want to learn something new.

Comment: If you want only 1 random record every time, write a procedure which should first get count(*) from your table. Then generate a random number  from 1 - count. Then select the record where rownumber = this random number.

Comment: No, I need it to be configurable. I sometimes need 3 random records and sometimes 10.

Comment: In that case, determine the number range for the max number of records you want, say 1 - 100. Get the count in C. Now generate a random number between this and save in a variable say N. Then run a loop from 1 - N. In the loop generate random number between 1 - C, call in R. Save different values of R. End the loop. Now select record from your table where rownum in (different values of R)

Comment: For 9.5 there are many various new possibilities: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/tablesample-and-other-methods-for-getting-random-tuples/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
ORDER BY random() LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: ORDER BY random() is very slow on large tables.

Answer (score 0):

I finished with something like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_random_id(in_table_name TEXT, want_elements INT4) RETURNS INT4[] as $BODY$

declare

    use_sql        TEXT;

    id_range       record;

    reply          INT4[];

    this_part      INT4[];

    try            INT4    := 0;

    i              INT4;

BEGIN

    use_sql := 'SELECT min(id), max(id) - min(id) + 1 as range FROM ' || quote_ident(in_table_name);

    EXECUTE use_sql INTO id_range;

    IF id_range.range < want_elements THEN

        raise exception 'not enough elements in % table.', in_table_name;

    END IF;

    WHILE ( try < 10 ) LOOP

        try := try + 1;

        this_part := '{}'::INT4[];

        WHILE ( coalesce(array_upper( this_part, 1 ), 0) < want_elements - coalesce(array_upper(reply, 1), 0)) LOOP

            i := floor( random() * id_range.range) + id_range.min;

            IF NOT i = ANY(this_part) THEN

                this_part := this_part || i;

            END IF;

        END LOOP;

        use_sql := 'SELECT id FROM ' || quote_ident(in_table_name) || ' WHERE id = ANY(' || quote_literal(this_part::TEXT) || '::INT4[])';

        for i IN EXECUTE use_sql LOOP

            reply := reply || i;

        END LOOP;

        IF (coalesce(array_upper(reply, 1), 0) = want_elements) THEN

            RETURN reply;

        END IF;

    END LOOP;

    RAISE EXCEPTION 'something strange happened - requested records not found in % tries', try;

END;

$BODY$ language plpgsql STABLE;
```

But there is one problem with that function. When I use it like this:

```
select first_name from people WHERE (difference(first_name, 'first_name') < 2) and id = any(get_random_id('people', 3));
```

it sometimes returns 3 records and sometimes 2 or 1... :(